# Meteor stuck on second server-side collection methods (with discord.js)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, discord

I'm trying to create a discord bot with web interface so I decide to use Meteor with Discord.js.

I found a problem when I call Mongo's methods on the server-side for the second time (First time is working fine) no matter which methods it is (I test with both remove() and findOne()) It's stuck there with no error on console.

Then I tried to change from mongo collection to array and it's work but I want to use collection to share the data with client side.

Here is my code, a song will start when user hit the button and play() ins meteor Methods is called:

**server/main.js**

```
import '../imports/queue.js';
import '../imports/bot.js';
```

**import/queue.js**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Queue = new Mongo.Collection('queue');
```

**import/bot.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Queue } from '../imports/queue';

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

    const token = 'my-token';
    const client = new Discord.Client();

    let streamSetting = { seek: 0, volume: 0.1 };

    voiceChannel = null;
    voiceConnection = null;
    dispatcher = null;

    // Discord bot preparation
    client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Unicot is running!');
    });

    client.on('message', m => {
        if (m.content === '>>hi') {
            if(voiceChannel == null) {
                //Get voiceChannel
                voiceChannel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.type === 'voice');

                //Join voiceChannel
                voiceChannel.join()
                    .then(connection => {
                        voiceConnection = connection;
                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
            }
        } else if(m.content === '>>bye') {
            if(voiceChannel != null) {
                //Leave voiceChannel
                voiceChannel.leave();
                voiceChannel = null;
            }
        }

    });

    client.login(token);

    //Dequeue Song
    function getNextSong() {
        console.log("getNextSong started");
        currentSong = Queue.findOne({});

        console.log("Got next song: "+currentSong.url);

        if(typeof currentSong != 'undefined') {
            //Play Stream
            playStream(currentSong);
        }
    }

    //Play Stream
    function playStream(currentSong) {
        if(dispatcher == null) {
            //stream song
            let stream = ytdl(currentSong.url, {filter : 'audioonly'});
            dispatcher = voiceConnection.playStream(stream,streamSetting);

            console.log("playing "+currentSong.url);

            dispatcher.on('end',function(currentSong) {
                if(dispatcher != null) {
                    console.log("Stream ended");
                    //Remove from queue
                    //currentSong = Queue.remove(currentSong);
                    console.log("Song removed");

                    dispatcher = null;
                    getNextSong();
                }
            })
        }
    }

    // Meteor Methods called from front-end
    Meteor.methods({
        'add': function(url) {
            Queue.insert({
                "url": url,
                "date": new Date()
            });

            playQueue.push({})
        },
        'play': function() {
            if(voiceConnection != null) {
                if(dispatcher == null) {
                    //No song playing
                    getNextSong();
                } else {
                    //Song is paused
                    dispatcher.resume();
                }
            }
        },
        'skip': function() {
            if(voiceConnection != null) {
                dispatcher = null;
                getNextSong();
            }
        },
        'pause': function() {
            if(voiceConnection != null) {
                dispatcher.pause();
            }
        },
        'remove': function(id) {
            console.log("removing");
        }
    })
}
```

**client/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';

import { Queue } from '../imports/queue.js';

angular.module('unicot', [
  angularMeteor
]).controller('mainController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
    /* Add song */
    $scope.add = function(url) {
      Meteor.call('add',url);
    }

    $scope.play = function() {
      Meteor.call('play');
    }

    $scope.pause = function() {
      Meteor.call('pause');
    }

    $scope.skip = function() {
      Meteor.call('skip');
    }

    $scope.helpers({
      queue() {
        return Queue.find({});
      },
    })
}]);
```

**Result from console**

```
I20170321-19:47:30.143(2)? Unicot is running!
I20170321-19:47:44.647(2)? getNextSong started
I20170321-19:47:44.648(2)? Got next song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPEE9ZwTmy0
I20170321-19:47:44.665(2)? playing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPEE9ZwTmy0
I20170321-19:47:48.041(2)? Stream ended
```

Comment: Can you share your client code that is actually calling your meteor methods?

Comment: @jordanwillis Of course! I just update my post. You can find it above. Thank you :)